# Can I use MessageBodyReader with Spring Boot?

Tags: rest, spring-boot

In earlier projects creating REST services with JAX-RS, I used a custom MessageBodyReader/MessageBodyWriter combo to handle the custom format sent to/from my services. All I had to do was create the custom class and register it with the REST App class.

I'm trying to do the same thing now using Spring Boot (my first time using Spring Boot), and I can't seem to figure out how to go about this. Is there some way for me to add the custom reader/writer classes to my SpringBoot REST services? Is there some other mechanism that's used in SpringBoot other than MessageBodyReader et al to handle custom formats like this?

Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot is just a bootstrapping framework. There's nothing REST related about it, besides the choice of REST framework one chooses to use *with* Spring boot. Two choices of frameworks that are officially supported by Spring boot are Spring MVC and Jersey (a JAX-RS implementation).  `MessageBodyReader` is a Jersey component. So you need to use Jersey as the REST framework. You can look at the [Spring Boot project samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey) to see how to get started with Jersey. There's also some documentation about it in the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jersey).

Once you get the app set up, based on the sample I linked to, all you need to do is call `register(YourReader.class)` inside your `ResourceConfig` constructor.

If your goal is to use Spring MVC as the REST framework, I am not sure what the `MessageBodyReader` equivalent would be. I don't really use that framework.

Answer (score 3):

The [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) doc describes this. You would want to create a `HttpMessageConverter` that specifies the content types that it can convert. You can check out the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for an example.